# Correctly Adding Style Resource Files to C# WPF Project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've read a lot about `ResourceDictionaries`, but I'm not sure what their relationship is with the filesystem.
If I reference a `ResourceDictionary Source="/X/a.b"`, does this mean I can put the resource file a.b under directory X, where X is the same directory with my `bin, obj, App.xaml`, etc.?

I'm trying to do such a thing with the Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles, but I'm receiving an error of `FileNotFound`.

> The assembly with display name 'Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles' failed to load
>   in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of
>   the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles, Culture=neutral' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've put all of the resources in the directory and have confirmed that the files match the file system expectations as I think they are meant to be.
Am I missing other conventions?

The code for importing the resources is:

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary 
            Source="pack://application:,,,/Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles;component/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Please put in the code you are using.

Comment: i'm sorry that this question isn't so clear as i would like.  if there is a way to improve it, that would be great.  i'm new to wpf

Comment: What is the build action property of the Styles.xaml file set to?

Comment: i had not added the xaml directly to my solution, so it had no build action property.  is it possible this is making the error?  that would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to load the resource file from an external assembly, named `Selen.Wpf.SystemStyles`. Inside there is an embedded resource file named `Styles.xaml`.

From the exception it seems you are missing a reference to the assembly mentioned or it didn't get copied to the `bin\Debug` directory.

Also read into the pack URIs on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(VS.85).aspx).